# @Request String payload in RestController for Post API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I am using @Request String for payload of Post API something as below :

```
@PutMapping("/{account}/accountid")
public ResponseEntity<Account> createAccount(@Valid @RequestBody String payload)
{
.........
//Later converting this String to pojo based on some condition
}
```

I know instead of String I should use Pojo for @RequestBody, But now it requires design change.
Is it bad design If i use the payload as String for @RequestBody, What are the disadvantages.
The String payload is something looks like below:

```
{
    "account": {
        "id": "1001",
        "name": "....",
        "test": ".........."
    },
    "test": {
"testing":"..."
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create A `DTO` pojo class for the incoming data and mapped to the internal entity, also you can use a library like ModelMapper or MapStruct that handles the conversion automatically.